# Implementing scrollbar inside canvas Attribute error

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm trying to implement a scrollbar inside a bigger program. I'm facing some AtrributeError issues. So, in order to fix this I made a simpler code which are shown below.

-The scrollbar have to scroll the canvas horizontally and not the text widget.

-This simpler program has only 2 tk.Text widgets (glued by '`side="left"`')

-The bigger program has 18 tk.Text so i really need the horizontal scrollbar

-I'm facing some canvas issues too, since the text widgets are not inside the canvas.

I've tried some solutions that already exists, but there are some divergences program wise which I can't read very well (since I'm not pro at tkinter). Could someone please help me, what is missing in my code to make this AtrributeError disappear?

I need the tk.Texts inside a canvas and the canvas itself are scrollable

EDIT1:
Now the program is like this, but the scrollbar isn't scrollable

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master)
        self.canvas.pack(side='top')
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.frame.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand=True)

        self.text = tk.Text(self.canvas, width= 5).pack(side='left')
        self.text2 = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5).pack(side='left')
        self.text3 = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5).pack(side='left')
        self.text4 = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5).pack(side='left')
        self.text5 = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5).pack(side='left')
        self.text6 = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5).pack(side='left')
        self.text7 = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5).pack(side='left')
        self.text8 = tk.Text(self.canvas, width=5).pack(side='left')

        self.scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient='horizontal', command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        self.canvas['xscrollcommand'] = self.scroll
        self.canvas["scrollregion"] = self.canvas.bbox('all')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x300')
test = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should never `pack`, `grid` of `place` any Tkinter widget as follows:

```
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master).pack(side='top')
```

This sets `self.canvas` to `None`. Rather do the following:

```
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master)
self.canvas.pack(side = 'top')
```

Secondly, there is a typo in the line `self.canvas['vscrollcommand']`. It should be `yscrollcommand`. Also the `yscrollcommand` needs to be assigned to the `Scrollbar` itseld and not to its `set` function, as follows:

```
self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scroll)
```

Lastly, set a `scrollregion` for the canvas as follows:

```
self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))
```

Comment: _" Also the yscrollcommand needs to be assigned to the Scrollbar itseld and not to its set function"_ - that is a false statement. It needs to point to the `set` method of the scrollbar, or some other function that implements the same API.

Comment: Using these conditions my scrollbar does not work properly, either shows with 'disabled' feature (it is there but not selectable)(using self.scroll.set) or the scrollbar is there but does not work properly (it isn't disabled, it is there but there is no window to drag  inside the scrollbar's bar). How to implement the correct way  of scrolling